# Filtering a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, filter

I am trying to start learning haskell, and a question came up.
Say, I have a function

```
countFilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], Int)
countFilter a z = case z of []        -> ([], 0);
                            (x:xs)    -> (filter a z , length (filter a z))
```

It returns a list, all the items of which apply to a certain predicate and a length of that list, which is not relevant.

`countFilter (<7) [1,2,4,7,11,8,2]` will output `([1,2,4,2], 4)`.

How to create such an output: `([7,11,8], 4)` using the same predicate (<7)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to return all the elements that *don't* match the predicate `(< 7)` as the first element of the pair.

In that case you can simply use the `not` function to flip the resulting boolean.
I.e. create a new predicate `(\x -> not (oldPred x))`, or using function composition: `(not . oldPred)`:

```
countFilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], Int)
countFilter f xs = (filter (not . f) xs, length (filter f xs))
```

Note that both `filter` and `length` can deal with empty lists, so you don't need to write a `case` yourself.

---

Alternatively, you can use the [partition](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-List.html#v%3apartition) function to create the two lists, so that you don't filter the list twice:

```
import Data.List

countFilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], Int)
countFilter f xs = let (ys, zs) = partition (not . f) xs
                   in (ys, length zs)
```

It's probably possible to create an even more efficient version that doesn't use `length`, but I leave that as an exercise :-)

Comment: excellent! I just didn't notice the "not" in the reference :) Tried to implement "negate" instead ... I didn't yet make it to partitions and importing thought, but I'll get back to your answer, as I'll continue on my Haskell-path.)